# Prolog compare list structure

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to compare two lists in prolog like

```
?- compare([[X],Y,Z],[[A],B,C]).
true.
?- compare([X,Y,Z],[[A],B,C]).
false.
```

I can't use the ==/2 operator because the logical variables aren't the same,
so this would evaluate false for both cases.
And I obviously cant use =/2 because this would evaluate true in both cases.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Words that start with uppercase letters are variables and words that start with lowercase letters are atoms. Do you really mean for A..C and X..Z to be variables?

Comment: @tom yes, i really meant logical variables.
I don't care about the content of the variable or even if its a logical variable or an atom. 
I rather want to compare the way of nesting and the amount of variables in the (nested) list.

Comment: @larsmans no, that would give would evaluate true for the second goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to match up list structures, perhaps something like this:

```
compare([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    is_list(H1),
    is_list(H2),
    compare(H1, H2),
    compare(T1, T2).
compare([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    \+ is_list(H1),
    \+ is_list(H2),
    compare(T1, T2).
compare([], []).

| ?- compare([[X],Y,Z],[[A],B,C]).

true ? ;

no
| ?- compare([X,Y,Z],[[A],B,C]).

no
```

The nice thing about this solution is that it will work whether the variables are instantiated or not.

```
| ?- compare([[a],b,c], [[d],X,f]).

true ? ;

no
| ?-
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution to check if two terms have the same structure is to use the ISO Prolog standard predicate `subsumes_term/2`. The following predicate, `variant/2` is true when a term is a variant of another term:

```
variant(Term1, Term2) :-
    \+ \+ subsumes_term(Term1, Term2),
    \+ \+ subsumes_term(Term2, Term1).
```

The use of double negation avoids instantiating any variables in the arguments. Using e.g. GNU Prolog for testing:

```
| ?- variant([[X],Y,Z],[[A],B,C]).

(1 ms) yes
| ?- variant([X,Y,Z],[[A],B,C]).

no
```

Comment: +1 never heard of `subsumes_term/2` before. How cool is that? :)

Comment: This doesn't work if the same variable name occurs in different places: `variant([A, B], [B, A]). no`

Comment: It's not supposed to as `[A,B]` isn't a variant of `[B,A]` unless `A = B`. E.g. if you do `A = 1, B = 2` you get `variant([1,2], [2,1])`. But Prolog compilers implementing `variant/2` or `(=@=)/2` do warn you about calling these predicates with shared variables between their arguments.

Comment: @PauloMoura, then I don't think this answers the question (taking into account the OP's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711893/prolog-compare-list-structure/20713406#comment31025646_20711893)).

Answer (score 1):

this works for the the presented test case

```
elemcmp(A,B) :- var(A), var(B), ! ; A =@= B.

?- maplist(elemcmp,[[X],Y,Z],[[A],B,C]).
true.

?- maplist(elemcmp,[X,Y,Z],[[A],B,C]).
false.
```

Comment: `maplist(elemcmp,[[A,A]],[[A,B]]).` is false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use (SWI Prolog, at least), [`=@=`/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compare#=@=/2). A test like `Term1 =@= Term2` is true

> if `Term1` is a variant of (or structurally equivalent to) `Term2`.
>   Testing for a variant is weaker than equivalence (`==`/2),
>   but stronger than unification (`=`/2).
>   Two terms `A` and `B` are variants iff [*sic*] there exists a renaming of the variables
>   in `A` that makes `A` equivalent (`==`) to `B` and vice versa.

Basically, `foo(A,B)` and `foo(B,C)` and `foo(C,D)` are are variants of each other, but not of `foo(A,A)`.

Tests against anonymous variable behaves as you might expect: `foo(_,_)` is a variant of `foo(A,B)`, but not of `foo(A,A)` (since all usages of the anonymous variable are distinct).

Comment: YAP also implements `(=@=)/2` as a built-in predicate. But note that it fails for cases where SWI-Prolog succeeds when there are shared variables between the arguments. E.g. the goal `[A, B] =@= [B, A]` fails on YAP but succeeds on SWI-Prolog. Better stick with a portable and standard-based solution, such as the one I posted, which relies on an ISO *specified* built-in predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
compare(A, B) :- (var(A); var(B)), !, var(A), var(B).
compare([], []).
compare([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :- compare(H1, H2), compare(T1, T2).
```

To also accept atoms, use `\+ is_list(...)` or equivalent instead of `var(...)`.

Comment: It doesn't solve the same problem though; @mbratch's code gets `true` for `compare([[a],b,c], [[d],X,f])` and yours does not. Not sure whether it matters to the inquirer or not though.